# How can I fetch the junk folder from office365 into another imap server?

Tags: directory, imap, office365

Office365 put the received mail in the INBOX folder, but also it puts many good emails in the junk folder.
How can I fetch the emails from the junk folder into a local imap account, putting them in the local junk folder?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
In Linux, beside the well known fetchmail program that fetch email from other pop3 or imap account, there is another very good program: getmail. With getmail it's possible to connect a remote imap server, fetch emails from a specific imap folder and put email in another local imap folder. For example, if I want to get emails from junk foder of outlook/office365 and put in the Junk folder of a local imap account, I have to:

install getmail: with debian distros, **apt install getmail**

**su - LOCALUSERNAME** where LOCALUSERNAME is the local imap account

**mkdir .getmail** then create the file *.getmail/getmailrc* with the following content:

```
[retriever]
type = SimpleIMAPSSLRetriever
server = outlook.office365.com
port = 993
username = EMAILADDRESS@OFFICE365.DOMAIN
password = PASSWORD
mailboxes = ("Posta Indesiderata",)
# office365 is really bad: mailbox name takes the localized name, so "Posta Indesiderata" in Italian language

[destination]
type = Maildir
path = LOCALUSERNAME/Maildir/.Junk/

[options]
message_log_syslog = true
message_log_verbose = true

# retrieve only new emails
read_all = false
# delete on server after x days
delete_after = 50
# do not add a Delivered-To: header field
delivered_to = false
# do not add a Received: header field
received = false
```

Then, type **getmail** to test what happen, and if everything goes well, add getmail to the cronjob: **crontab -e** and put inside the line

```
*/5 * * * * getmail
```